# How can i load views of other tabs on the app launch?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewdidload

For better user experience purpose I want to load other tabs in advance.

I have 4 tabs in my UITabBarController , and viewDidLoad() for each UIViewController is called when user selects that particular tab except first view controller.

what is the best way to load views in other tabs when App is launched , before user selects that tab?

Comment: Is view loading really the problem or have you conflated it with some other concern like loading data over the network? Rather than trying to change the view loading lifecycle its usually preferable to decouple the behavior you need from view loading so you can trigger it directly.

Comment: @Jonah, My NSFetchedResultsController is in the second tab and i save some data in coredata in my first tab , NSFetchedResultsController is not working as expected unless that tab is loaded before the data is saved.

Comment: The view controllers of different tabs should not have any dependencies on each other. Each view controller should stand on its own.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem; some confusion around the use of NSFetchedResultsController. Working with models in Core Data should not depend on UIViewController view state. However since we can't see your controller's implementation there's not enough detail in this question to offer a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force the `viewDidLoad` method to be called, you simply need to reference the `view` property of the view controller.

Something like this would do it:

```
_ = someViewController.view // causes `viewDidLoad` to be called.
```

Comment: this code is a failure

Answer (score 0):

Try to call [`loadViewIfNeeded()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621446-loadviewifneeded) method on each view controller from `UITabBarController`'s stack. According to the documentation it

> Loads the view controller’s view if it has not yet been loaded.

You can find all the `UITabBarController`'s view controllers via its [`viewControllers`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621185-viewcontrollers) property.